# Does removing an imported *.adm template from a GPO also disable all settings?

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I have a GPO that consists of several imported `*.adm` templates, which I now need to remove (due to an update to the software they relate to).

I know how to remove the templates, but I can't find any documentation on the effects of removing them.

Is anyone able to tell me if I need to go through and disable all of the settings in the custom templates before I remove them, or if just straight up removing them will do the trick? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't and yes you do.

If you don't, the settings will remain in the GPO but won't be changeable.

Comment: Thanks, that's very annoying. If only MS weren't lazy and added a 'reset keys' option to parent nodes!